# How to make this request correct in Yii2?

Tags: mysql, database, yii2

I need to do this request using \yii\db\Query().
How I can do it? I have this request and it works well in the PHPMyAdmin, but I can't  repeat this using \yii\db\Query(). This is my SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    `z`.idzadaniya,
    `r`.id
FROM
    `zadaniya` AS `z`
LEFT JOIN
    `result` AS `r`
ON
    `r`.zadaniya_idzadaniya = `z`.idzadaniya AND `r`.created_at IN(
    SELECT
        MAX(`r`.created_at)
    FROM
        `zadaniya` AS `z`
    JOIN
        `result` AS `r`
    ON
        z.idzadaniya = r.zadaniya_idzadaniya
    GROUP BY
        `z`.idzadaniya
)
```

This is the request that I want to make, but I cannot implement it using \yii\db\Query(). The request returns not all that I need. It does not return null values and not the current $subQuery.

```
 $subQuery = (new \yii\db\Query())->select(['max(r.created_at)'])->from('zadaniya AS z');

    return $rows = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['z.idzadaniya','r.id'])->from('zadaniya AS z')
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'result AS r', 'r.zadaniya_idzadaniya = z.idzadaniya')
        ->andWhere(['result.created_at'=>$subQuery])
        ->join('LEFT JOIN', 'result', 'z.idzadaniya = result.zadaniya_idzadaniya')
        ->groupBy('z.idzadaniya')
        ->all();
```

What I want to get. See picture 1. (correct)
[image: SQL Query return this (correct)]

What I get. See picture 2. Not correct for me
[image: yii\db\Query return (not correct for me)]

Comment: try `$subQuery = new Query();
        $subQuery->select([new Expression('MAX(r.created_at)')])
                ->from('zadaniya z')
                ->leftJoin('zadaniya z','z.idzadaniya = r.zadaniya_idzadaniya')
                ->groupBy('z.idzadaniya');

        $query = new Query();
        $query->select('z.idzadaniya,r.id')
                ->from('zadaniya z')
                ->leftJoin('result r', ['AND',
                            ['=','r.zadaniya_idzadaniya','z.idzadaniya'], 
                            ['IN','r.created_at',$subQuery]
                        ])->all();`

Comment: add the namespaces on top of your page `use yii\db\Query`, `use yii\db\Expression`